# How to calculate cumulative moving average in Python/SQLAlchemy/Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'll give some context so it makes sense. I'm capturing Customer Ratings for Products in a table (Rating) and want to be able to return a Cumulative Moving Average of the ratings based on time.

A basic example follows taking a rating per day:

```
02 FEB - Rating: 5 - Cum Avg: 5
03 FEB - Rating: 4 - Cum Avg: (5+4)/2 = 4.5
04 FEB - Rating: 1 - Cum Avg: (5+4+1)/3 = 3.3
05 FEB - Rating: 5 - Cum Avg: (5+4+1+5)/4 = 3.75
Etc...
```

I'm trying to think of an approach that won't scale horribly.

My current idea is to have a function that is tripped when a row is inserted into the Rating table that works out the Cum Avg based on the previous row for that product

So the fields would be something like:

```
TABLE: Rating
| RatingId | DateTime | ProdId | RatingVal | RatingCnt | CumAvg |
```

But this seems like a fairly dodgy way to store the data.

What would be the (or any) way to accomplish this? If I was to use the 'trigger' of sorts, how do you go about doing that in SQLAlchemy?

Any and all advice appreciated!

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this in SQL -- see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107479/subqueries-aggregates-and-aggravation/4107784#4107784 ... I'm not sure how to get SQLAlchemy to generate a query like that though (and your database may not support the necessary syntax.)

Comment: @Sean Vieria: Thanks for the link - I know it's possible in pure SQL, but again this means as the # of ratings grows, the performance gets worse as the calculations are made on each row. I might try implement my original idea of storing it as each row is entered as I know that will scale. I just wasn't sure whether there was something basic I was overlooking. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about SQLAlchemy, but I might use an approach like this:

- Store the cumulative average and rating count separately from individual ratings.
- Every time you get a new rating, update the cumulative average and rating count:

  - new_count = old_count + 1
  - new_average = ((old_average * old_count) + new_rating) / new_count
- Optionally, store a row for each new rating.

Updating the average and rating count could be done with a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented most of it yesterday and this is the approach I ended up taking anyway, I've just got to finish implementing it and then I'll post back the code I used. It scales responsibly and predictably, which is what I was after.

Comment: And if the user can edit the rating? This approach would work?

Comment: It's a lot easier to store the *sum* and the count, rather than the *average* and the count.