# Edit rating of cumulative average

Tags: sql, algorithm, math, logic, rating

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157768/how-to-calculate-cumulative-moving-average-in-python-sqlalchemy-flask/7183579#comment45302938_7183579) about cumulative average.

The answer looks good to a general purpose. However I am trying to find if the same approach could be used if the user can edit the rating. I tried to know what the user of accepted answer thinks but he did not reply. So I am creating a new question.

> Every time you get a new rating, update the cumulative average and
>    rating count:

```
new_count = old_count + 1 
new_average = ((old_average * old_count) + new_rating) / new_count
```

If the user can edit the rating:

```
new_count = old_count // With a rating edit, the count will be the same
new_average = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to keep a running sum `S` and count `C`. When a new rating `R` is added, the update rule is the following.

```
(S, C) <- (S + R, C + 1)               | When a new rating R is added.
(S, C) <- (S - R, C - 1)               | When a rating R is removed.
```

To get the average at any time, simply evaluate `S / C`. When a rating that is part of `S` is modified, update as follows, where `R0` is the old rating and `R1` is the new rating.

```
(S, C) <- (S - R0 + R1, C)             | When rating R0 is changed to R1.
```

There is no reason to store your data as average `A` and count `C`. It just makes the updates more complicated.

```
(A, C) <- ((CA + R) / (C + 1), C + 1)  | When a new rating R is added.
(A, C) <- (A + (R1 - R0) / C, C)       | When rating R0 is changed to R1.
```

Comment: I am still working on this. But how do you make an order by rating with this type of implementation? I don't have a db field to make an order by avg_rating. I am using sql achmemy. thanks

Comment: @user2990084 For that I would have a third column so that your columns are Sum, Count, and Average.  The Sum and Count are updated as I describe above.  The Average is recomputed based on the Sum and Count every time they are updated.  Think of the Average as being derived from the Sum and Count, such that you're never directly modifying the Average column.  If you do this, you will then be able to order by the Average column.

Comment: apparently I can do S/C in the order by. So i can avoid the column Average. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract out the old value and add in the new:

```
new_average = old_average + (new_rating - old_rating) / count
```

This means that you have to store all the old ratings somewhere.  However, if your users are going to be editing them, then presumably you have the old values somewhere.